# Write an ActiveRecord association statement for Inner Join query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

There are three table namely attendances,students and subjects for which I am unsuccessfully trying to do build an inner join query using active record.

***Desired sql query***

The raw sql statement that fetches correct data is

```
SELECT * FROM attendances AS a
INNER JOIN subjects AS b ON a.subject_id = b.id
WHERE b.organization LIKE  '%city%'
AND a.started_at BETWEEN  '2016-07-11 02:59:00' AND  '2016-07-11 09:00:00'
```

The above query fetches exactly the correct 30 rows. However the problem arises when I try to perform the same with active-record associations.

***Active-record associations***

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection ({ adapter: 'mysql2',host:'localhost',
username: 'testuser',password: '***',database: 'database'})  


class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendances
  has_many :students, through: :attendances
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendances
  has_many :subjects, through: :attendances
end

class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subject
  belongs_to :student
end

data = Attendance.
where(started_at:  start_date..end_date).
joins(:subject).
where(subjects: {:organization => city}).
pluck(:subject_id,:name,:duration,:started_at,:student_id)
```

Using _to_sql_ and after removing the :pluck, the sql query generated by active record is

```
SELECT `attendances`.* FROM `attendances` INNER JOIN `subjects` 
         ON `subjects`.`id` = `attendances`.`subject_id` 
         WHERE (`attendances`.`started_at` BETWEEN '2016-07-11 02:59:00' 
         AND '2016-07-11 09:59:00') 
         AND `subjects`.`organization` = 'city'
```

Modifying the statement to the below one doesn't help either.

```
data = Attendance.joins(:subject).
where('started_at BETWEEN ? AND ?','2016-07-11 02:59:00','2016-07-11 09:59:00').
where(subjects: {:organization => 'city'}).
pluck(:subject_id,:name,:duration,:started_at,:student_id)
```

The sql query generated for the above statement after removing :pluck using _to_sql_ as suggested is

```
 SELECT `attendances`.* FROM `attendances` INNER JOIN `subjects` 
 ON    `subjects`.`id` = `attendances`.`subject_id` 
 WHERE (started_at BETWEEN '2016-07-11 02:59:00' AND '2016-07-11 09:59:00') 
AND `subjects`.`organization` = 'city'
```

Both the above active-record statement results in additional irrelavent rows being fetched. I am unable generate the desired correct sql query as shown earlier.

Constructing a correct active record statement or associations would be really helpful.

environment:-

```
ruby 2.1.6
activerecord 4.2.4
```

Comment: Try this `data = Attendance.joins(:subject).where('started_at BETWEEN ? AND ?','2016-07-11 02:59:00','2016-07-11 09:59:00').where('organization LIKE ?', 'city').pluck(:subject_id,:name,:duration,:started_at,:organization,:student_id)`

Comment: try using [`to_sql`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/to_sql) to see what query it makes

Comment: Please format your code for readability and to eliminate scrolling.

Comment: @ArunKumar That don't seems to work either. But thanks for the heads up. As suggested in previous comment I will try to convert the statement to raw sql using _to_sql_

Comment: @tihom Thanks for tip, will post the sql format of the active record statement.